# How do I pass the address of a 3-dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, parameters, multidimensional-array

I have 4 " #defines " :

```
    #define MAX_NO_OF_ROUTES    15
    #define MAX_STOPS_IN_ROUTE  50
    #define RAIL_SYMBOL_LEN     3
    #define READ_ADDR       25236
```

I have a 3-dimensional array declared like this :

```
    unsigned char ram_route_info[MAX_NO_OF_ROUTES][MAX_STOPS_IN_ROUTE][RAIL_SYMBOL_LEN];
```

I have a "for" loop as follows :

```
    for(i = 0 ; i < MAX_NO_OF_ROUTES ; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < MAX_STOPS_IN_ROUTE ; ++j)
        {
            // read from Flash into ram !!
            HL_flash2ram(READ_ADDR, &ram_route_info[i][j][0]);
        }
    }
```

The prototype of "HL_flash2ram" function is

```
    void HL_flash2ram(long addr, unsigned char* );
```

On compiling, however, I get the warning :

```
    warning C182: pointer to different objects
```

I'm using KEIL compiler. I've even tried the following :

```
    ram_route_info[i][j]
    &(ram_route_info[i][j])
    ram_route_info[i][j][0]
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: This looks OK to me. `&ram_route_info[i][j][0]` is of type `unsigned char *`. Please show the entire function where the two `for` statements are used.

Comment: could it be a compiler issue then ? Maybe it cannot handle an array having more than 2 dimensions??

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as an 'unsigned char ***'. (that is three asterisk)

Answer (score 0):

Pass this way

prototype of the function must be

```
  void HL_flash2ram(long addr, unsigned char  arr[][MAX_STOPS_IN_ROUTE][RAIL_SYMBOL_LEN] );
```

or

```
void HL_flash2ram(long addr, unsigned char* arr);
```

But in the last case access to an element arr[a][b][c] is to be performed so

```
*(arr + a*MAX_STOPS_IN_ROUTE*RAIL_SYMBOL_LEN + b*RAIL_SYMBOL_LEN + c)
```